# Storing query result into a variable

Tags: c#, variable-types, dynamictype

I'm a very beginner of C# and have some troubles with correct understading of generic types. In this example I would like to somehow store a query result into a variable.

The code I showed below is incorrect, because generic type T should specified.

```cs
    public class Data
    {
        public IQueryable<T> Results { get; set; }

        public Data()
        {
            var db = new Database();
        }
        public void Store()
        {
            Results = db.Products.Select(x => new { x.ProductName, x.Cost });
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to do it without declaring a special class for only one use, like this one?

```
public class ProductView 
{
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public int Country { get; set; }
}
...
public IQueryable<ProductView > Results { get; set; }
```

Also, why dynamic type doesn't suit in this example?

```
public dynamic Results { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 ways to solve this problem:

1) Create class like `ProductView` that you mentioned - classical C#6 or older way

2) Use `dynamic` instead of `T` like: `public IQueryable<dynamic> Results { get; set; }` - not recommended, because it increases risk of runtime errors and reduces readability

3) Use [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) (C#7 feature):

```
public IQueryable<(string, int)> Results { get; set; } // I suppose ProductName is string and Cost is int

public void Store()
{
    Results = db.Products.Select(x => (x.ProductName, x.Cost));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `Data` class appears to know some specific things about `T`. In the `Store` method it reads the `Products` and obtains two specific properties from each item. So it is not actually a generic class that can store any type. It's very specific.

To make it generic you would need to remove the `Store` method. And then there is not much left. You need to decide what the purpose of `Data` is. What problem does it exist to solve?